# Ads.txt not found - properly configure htaccess for https redirection

Tags: .htaccess, https, http-redirect

I am trying to get Google to find my ads.txt file.

At present I have problems trying to access it via HTTP (404 error):

- http://leblonblue.com/ads.txt or
- http://www.leblonblue.com/ads.txt

But on https it works fine:

- https://leblonblue.com/ads.txt or
- https://www.leblonblue.com/ads.txt

I figure something must be wrong with my .htaccess file which at present reads:

```
RewriteEngine On
RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ https://leblonblue.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]
```

Any help will be highly appreciated

Thanks!

-- Edit

Placing redirect before the other stuff as suggested by CBroe

```
RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ https://leblonblue.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]
```

Comment: You should do your HTTPS redirect before the other stuff.

Comment: @CBroe, like:

RewriteEngine On

RewriteCond %{HTTPS} off [OR]
RewriteCond %{HTTP_HOST} ^www\. [NC] 
RewriteRule ^ https://leblonblue.com%{REQUEST_URI} [R=301,L,NE]

RewriteBase /
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ - [L]

RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-f
RewriteCond %{REQUEST_FILENAME} !-d
RewriteRule . /index.php [L]

Comment: Please add that to your question, properly formatted, this is hardly readable in a comment.

Comment: you are right, done

Comment: Not even `http://leblonblue.com` works, that gives a 404 already. Looks like your setup does not even route that kind of request into your project directory correctly to begin with? I’m guessing this is something you have to fix in your Google domain setup somehow.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

As CBroe suggested, problem was actually on my server configuration.

I removed the redirect rules from htaccess and fixed my loadbalancer to properly route http.